# Conditions equivalent to the surjectivity of a function

Tags: elementary-set-theory, functions

> Show that the following are equivalent for a map $f:X \to Y$.
>
> 1. $\,f$ is a surjection.
> 2. $\,f[f^{-1}[B]]=B$ for each $B \subseteq Y$.
> 3. $\,f^{-1}[B] \subsetneq f^{-1}[C]$ for each $B \subsetneq C \subseteq Y$.

Comment: $f^{-1}$ does not mean the inverse of $f$ - $f$ may not have an inverse in general. Have you see the definition of $f^{-1}(B)$ for a set $B$?

Comment: Where exactly do you have problems to prove that? Is there no implication/ equivalence you are able to show?

Answer (score 2):

Proof.

$1.\,\Longrightarrow\, 2.$ The "$\subset$" part holds always, even if $f$ is not surjective, since if $y\in f\big[f^{-1}[B]\big]$, then $y=f(x)$, for some $x\in f^{-1}[B]$, and thus $y=f(x)\in B$. For the "$\supset$" part, let $y\in B$.
Since $f$ is surjective, there exists an $x\in f^{-1}[B]$, such that $f(x)=y$, and thus, $y=f(x)\in f[f^{-1}[B]]$.

$2.\,\Longrightarrow\, 3.$ Assume now that $B \subsetneq C \subset Y$. As it is clear that $f^{-1}[B]\subset f^{-1}[C]$, we need to show the strict inequality. Let $y\in C\smallsetminus B$. Since $f$ is surjective, there exists an $x\in f^{-1}[C\smallsetminus B]\subset f^{-1}[C\smallsetminus B]$, for which $f(x)=y$. But $x\not\in f^{-1}[B]$, because if $x\in f^{-1}[B]$, then $y=f(x)\in f^{-1}[B]$. Therefore $f^{-1}[B]\subsetneq f^{-1}[C]$.

$3.\,\Longrightarrow\, 1.$ Let $y\in Y$, we need to show, assuming 3.,  that there exist a $x\in X$, such that $f(x)=y$. Clearly $\varnothing\subsetneq \{y\}\subset Y$. Due to 3. $$
f^{-1}[\varnothing]\subsetneq f^{-1}[\{y\}]. \tag{1}
$$ 
But, as $f^{-1}[\varnothing]=\varnothing$, $(1)$ implies that  $f^{-1}[\{y\}]\ne\varnothing$. For every $x\in f^{-1}[\{y\}]$, we know that $f(x)=y$. And this concludes the proof.

Answer (score 0):

I think, as a commenter pointed out, that your confusion stems from misunderstanding what $f^{-1}[B]$ means when $B \subseteq Y$.

Here, since we really don't know that the function $f$ is invertible, we can't assume that $f^{-1}$ stands for a function $ f^{-1} : X \leftarrow Y$. Instead, it means the *[preimage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_%28mathematics%29#Inverse_image)* under $f$ of $B$. That is, the set of all $x \in X$ with $f(x) \in B$.

I think with this definition, you should be fine. Also, when you have to show the equivalence of $n > 2$ conditions, it's sometimes easier to try to prove $(1) \implies (2) \implies (3) \implies (1)$ (or some permutation thereof!) to save yourself from work.